# Deleting answer to reveal downvoter

Tags: discussion, down-votes, deleted-answers

Today I came across this
[disturbing comment](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/13592#comment53590_13592)

> If a particular user is suspected, one can make 100% sure of this by
>   deleting downvoted answers, observing appropriate reputation changes in a
>   few minutes and undeleting.

Is this type of activity condoned? No one wants to be downvoted, but I thought
it was supposed to be anonymous?

Comment: The correlation is not instant and doesn't prove anything. It'll be nothing more than speculation still.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216843/delay-answer-downvote-rep-loss-to-voter-to-help-hide-voters-identity

Comment: If by disturbing you mean fuel for conspiracies, then yes